# Decoding opcode to instruction

Tags: assembly, opcode, x86

First 2 instructions of this assembly routine are written directly in machine code, how to translate them to standard form (i guess it is something like *add %bp, %bx*, but it makes no sense since this routine is supposed to empty 8042 buffer) ?

```
   func:
        .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
        in  $64, %al
        test    %al, $2
        jnz func
        ret
```

Comment: That's called disassembling. Use the instruction set reference if you want to do it by hand, or use a disassembler.

Comment: Remember, data is stored little-endian.  The `.word` is equivalent to `.byte 0xeb, 0x00`.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use the debugger for this.

`db 0EBh, 00h` is a null jump, i.e. a jump to the instruction immediately following.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on 500 - Internal Sever Error's answer, the code is:

```
func:   jmp     short func0
func0:  jmp     short func1
func1:  in      $64, %al
        test    %al, $2
        jnz     func
        ret
```

The two jumps to the next instruction are used to create a short delay. This may be needed on some 8088 / 8086 / 80186 / 80286 / ... type environments when operating with certain I/O ports. For example, in the early days of the IBM AT's, in some cases, the AT / ISA bus ran a bit faster than the speeds that some older ISA type peripheral cards were designed to run at, so jump to next instruction was used as a delay.